# How to identify that the MailItem opened in the Inspector is an attachment to another MailItem?

Tags: office-interop, outlook-addin, add-in, office-addins, addin-express

I need to identify if the selected 'MailItem'(Inspector or Explorer) is an attachment of another MailItem. I've done a lot of research and I have not identified any way to do that.
I need to identify if it is an attachment of another message because I would like to edit the body of the message and save those changes. But if it's an attachment I can not change the body of the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the MailItem is being opened from an attachment, it will be read-only, according to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dd1b6b5c-3175-4bad-86f3-08cccd94c8cc/outlook-2010-you-dont-have-appropriate-permission-to-perform-this-operation?forum=outlookdev).
So, you can try to get the property PR_ACCESS_LEVEL from the MailItem, like this:

```
object accessLevel = mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FF70003");
```

According to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc979219.aspx), it will return:

- 0, when the MailItem is read-only;
- 1, when it is possible to modify the MailItem.

Answer (score 1):

The [EntryID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-entryid-property-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of Outlook items will be empty (like in case of newly created items).